# PHP search array return all values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a json file with data as below:

```
[
  {
    id: 40807,
    dl: true
  },
  {
    id: 347984,
    dl: true
  },
  {
    id: 431530,
    dl: true
  },
  {
    id: 75674,
    dl: true
  },
  {
    id: 262504,
    dl: true
  },
  {
    id: 415842,
    dl: false
  }
]
```

I am converting this to a PHP using json_decode.

I want to search the array for the id and return whether dl is true or false, but can't work out how to do this with PHP.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit:

I'm specifically pulling data from an API (The Movie Database). The API returns six movies with data such as biography, release date, ID, etc.

My json file above will contain a list of movies which I have in my collection (legally owned I might add).

I'm using a foreach loop to display the movie from the API. Within that, I'd like to search the array pulled from my json file to display whether that movie is in my collection.

I have the following:

```
//pull json data from TMBD API
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$APIurl);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($result, true);


$json = file_get_contents('PHP/results.json');
$cMov = json_decode($json,true);


$i=1;
foreach($obj['results'] as $data) {

    //search $cMov for $data['id']. Here I want to show whether 'dl' is true or false
    if(array_search($data['id'], array_column($cMov, 'tmdbid'))) {
        $exists = '&nbsp; <i style="color: #28B463;">Movie Exists in json file</i>';
    } else {
        $exists = '&nbsp; <i style="color: #CB4335;">Movie not in json file</i>';
    }

if($data["original_language"] == 'en') {

    //display movie poster, etc. echo $exists

    if(++$i >= $limit) break;
}


}
```

At the moment, that code will display whether the ID exists in my json library. However, I want to return the value of 'dl' also which differentiates between movies I own and movies I want to own.

I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To shortest way is to use `array_column()` using the option which allows you to set a key for the result...

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$out = array_column($data, "dl", "id");
echo $out[347984];
```

**Edit**

I've updated the code with the extra bits...

```
$data = json_decode($cMovJSON, true);
$cMov = array_column($data, "dl", "id");

foreach($obj['results'] as $data) {

    //search $cMov for $data['id']. Here I want to show whether 'dl' is true or false
    if(isset($cMov[$data['id']])) {
        $exists = '&nbsp; <i style="color: #28B463;">Movie Exists in json file</i>';
        if ( $cMov[$data['id']] )   {
            $exists.="True";  // Exists and true
        }
        else    {
            $exists.="False";// Exists but false
        }
    } else {
        $exists = '&nbsp; <i style="color: #CB4335;">Movie not in json file</i>';
    }

    if($data["original_language"] == 'en') {

        //display movie poster, etc. echo $exists

        if(++$i >= $limit) break;
    }

}
```

Hopefully you can see the bits where you can put whatever logic you need into this code.

Comment: I've updated my original question with more info.Thanks for your help

Comment: Think I've managed to update the answer with what your after.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have an array with obj, just loop throught it and check if "dl" is true or false :

```
// $array is your array as your wrote it
foreach ($array as $obj) {
  // $obj here is the "little" array you have with "id" and "dl"
  if ($obj['dl'] == true) {
    echo $obj; // eg. [id : xxx, dl : true]
    echo $obj['id']; // eg. xxx
  }
}
```

Now you can rebuild a new array with only value when 'dl' is true, you can add a new condition like `if ($obj['id'] == "THE ID YOU WANT")`, etc.

If you want to find a value in your array with a specific "id" and "dl" true, you can use `array_filter()` I think, here is the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

I'm not sure what you want to achieve exactly, is it what you are looking for?

Comment: I've updated my original question with more info.Thanks for your help